# AC voltage regulator in parallel

Tags: voltage-regulator, ac, parallel

I have two voltage regulator which works on ac. They are both the same model and provide a maximum power of 3000w.

I would like to plug their outputs together to make a 6000w total voltage regulator. It doesn't matter if one works harder than the other. I know it's easy to achieve this with diodes when the voltage regulator output direct current.

To be short, I think I need to isolate both regulator from each other while both being able to output the current on one source. (Although I'm not even sure if they really need to be isolated.)

I've been trying to do it with diodes but without success. I keep facing the problem of alternating current which needs to go in both ways.

Thank you for your help. I have a little knowledge in electronics and still beginning.

Here is the model of the voltage regulator:
LiteFuze LR-3000

Comment: Help us to help you. Post links to the datasheet for the regulators, or at least part number and manufacturer.

Comment: This is a "mains" power question that belongs over in diy.stackexchange.  The unit is a step up/down transformer intended to run European appliances in North America or vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most common AC 'regulators' use triacs and control power (it's not really a voltage regulator) by turning on the switch later and later in the AC cycle, a later turn on means less power (it's duty cycle control really), I don't see any major issues paralleling them, although unless they are well synchronised, one will take full power for a brief instant before the second switches on as well, although if the peak current ratings of most triacs and SCRs is anything to go by, that's unlikely to be an issue (10x current handling for one half cycle is quite common)